JPA @Version annotation with @Query
Our entities has version field, which works fine with Spring Data JPA repository methods taking entity as an argument. However, for JPA modifying queries version doesn't get upgraded, why?
public class Foo {

  @Column(name = "VERSION")
  @Version
  private Long version;
}

public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "UPDATE Foo foo SET foo.bar = 'hello' WHERE foo.id = :id)")
  void updateFoo(@Param("id") Long id);
}

I would like for updateFoo-method to increment the version also (without adding it to query by hand).

If you asking "why?" then think what is the point? Version here for optimistic locking. So when you read and save you can be sure no one updated entity in between. With using update query there is no "in between" so there is no point of involving version.

What? Of course there is, how else other transactions detect changed version?

On the second thought you are right. It doesn't mater for current transaction, but other transaction may be interested in change.

@Modifying and @Version Related Situation:

Automatic Update of Version Field: JPA automatically updates the field marked with @Version, but this is only done with standard operations such as find or save. If you are doing a manual update using @Modifying, you need to include the version information in the @Modifying query so that the version number is incremented.
When Optimistic Locking is Wanted: If you are doing an UPDATE query using @Modifying, you may need to update the version number yourself.
Here is an example of how to manage the version field when performing an UPDATE with @Modifying:


public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "UPDATE Foo foo SET foo.bar = 'hello' foo.version = foo.version + 1 WHERE foo.id = :id)")
  void updateFoo(@Param("id") Long id);
}

The version value is updated manually (i.e. we increase the version number by 1 with each UPDATE operation).
At the same time, we compare it with the current version value in the WHERE condition to provide optimistic locking. If the version value does not match (i.e. another operation has changed the version number), this operation will not be executed and an OptimisticLockException error will be thrown.

No OptimisticLockException will be thrown. I think one should check number of updated rows and throw it in the case of JPQL

When you use JPQL, HQL or SQL with JPA, JPA bypasses all the entity lifecycle stuff und just translates the query to SQL and executes it.
This behaviour also applies to Spring Data JPA when you specify modifying queries.
If you want the version attribute to be checked and updated, you have to include that in your update statment yourself, and also check if you actually updated the row in question.
